# Storing and retrieving values to a file on a cloud in Python

Tags: python, web

I have developed a search engine using Python. Whenever I run my program, it takes lot of time to collect keywords to the index since its a very big process.

So i'm just going to store the keywords onto a file so that I can retrieve it whenever I want.

Can I have the file on a cloud server so as to store and retrieve the values onto it?  If so, how do I do it?

Comment: How exactly will retrieving your keyword file from the cloud be faster than reading it from the local machine?

Comment: if its a local machine, thn there will be no privacy and safety factors for it. thats y i'm seeking file on cloud.

Comment: So you're saying cloud storage is more private than a privately owned server? Okay... whatever. The security part (if you're talking about secure backup solutions and not access security) could be achieved via dropbox or other storage services without the need to actually load the file from the cloud every time you want to use it.

Comment: First of all, you should acknowledge that you are just playing around in order to understand new technology. To me it looks like you wanna put keywords (whereever you got those from) together with some other information into a database and look this information up later on. Therefore, you want to learn something about (relational) databases, how to set up a database server and a database and how to interact with that database from Python.

Comment: Why aren't you using a database rather than a file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you are tryign to accomplish but amazon has a nicely supported very popular python library for interacting with most, if not all, of their cloud services.

https://github.com/boto/boto

Including s3